# R tmap: How to adjust the legend frame line width

Tags: r, tmap

I am trying to make a map with the cool `tmap` package and I cannot figure it out how to adjust the legend frame line width. I checked the impressive list of `tm_layout` arguments, but the closest I found was `frame.lwd` However,that refers to the frame of the map. I took the guess with `legend.frame.lwd` but that is not defined. Here is a toy example:

```
library(tmap)
data(Europe)

tm_shape(Europe) +
  tm_polygons("well_being", textNA="Non-European countries", title="Well-Being Index") +
  tm_text("iso_a3", size="AREA", root=5) +
  tm_layout(legend.position = c("RIGHT","TOP"),
            legend.frame = TRUE,
            frame.lwd = 5) # legend.frame.lwd does not exist
```

[image]

Comment: If you need a quick solution and you don't need to do it dynamically. You can save as pdf and use `inkscape`

Comment: Hi @AndreElrico. I would be curious about an `R/tmap` solution. But, indeed, I keep Inkscape as a viable option.

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible. You can [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues) with a request to add this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Jaap. It is now an [open issue here](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues/174)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the newer versions of `tmap`, the argument `legend.frame.lwd` was included with [this commit](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/commit/aaf82f2f8db750406f5ff5be90cdb58873015255). Here is an example, using `tmap` version 2.2:

```
library(tmap)
data("World")

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI") +
  tm_layout(legend.frame = TRUE,
            frame.lwd = 5,
            legend.frame.lwd = 5)
```

[image]